# Determine original size of image cross browser?

Tags: javascript, image

Is there a reliable, framework independent way of determining the physical dimensions of a `<img src='xyz.jpg'>` resized on the client side?

Comment: `img.onload = function () {console.log(img.height, img.width)} `

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**Option 1:**

Remove the `width` and `height` attributes and read `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`

**Option 2:**

Create a JavaScript `Image` object, set the `src`, and read the `width` and `height` (you don't even have to add it to the page to do this).

```
function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
    var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function() {
      var height = newImg.height;
      var width = newImg.width;
      alert ('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
    }

    newImg.src = imgSrc; // this must be done AFTER setting onload
}
```

**Edit by Pekka**: As agreed in the comments, I changed the function to run on the ´onload´ event of the image. Otherwise, with big images, `height` and `width` would not return anything because the image was not loaded yet.

Comment: That won't work with images that aren't loaded yet. It might be worth adjusting it to work properly for other people stumbling across this answer.

Comment: @Gabriel, I am using this but with an `newImg.onload` function to make sure the image is loaded when I set the width/height. Are you ok with me editing your answer accordingly?

Comment: Just a side note: Chrome/OSX can have problems with cached images where you get 0 as height/width using this technique.

Comment: how ca i get return hieght and width...?? because those variable are not getting outside of onload

Comment: @jafar: That's more complicated than I would like to put into a comment.  If I were you, I would ask that as a question of its own.  Include the source from here, and maybe a link to here in your question.

Comment: @GabrielMcAdams, if you add `if(newImg.complete || newImg.readyState === 4) newImg.onload();` at the end of your function it will fix the issue on Chrome/OSX that causes onload not to fire when images are loaded from cache.

Comment: Note that I tried with a base64 image that was just dragged and dropped and even with those you need to use the onload handler to get the right dimensions.

Comment: I've also seen a problem in Firefox, that the picture dimensions would not be loaded even if the onload function is called. I fixed it with a timeout.

Answer (score 118):

Images (on Firefox at least) have a `naturalWidth`/height property so you can use `img.naturalWidth` to get the original width

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
img.onload=function(){
    console.log("Width",img.naturalWidth);
    console.log("Height",img.naturalHeight);
}
```

[Source](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showpost.php?p=951590&postcount=15)

Comment: This topic is still relevant in 2013. Here's a link with a great workaround for IE7/8: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie/

Comment: This is the winning answer in 2018. Works everywhere. (Per [browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Browser_compatibility) at MDN.)

Comment: `if (currentYear >= 2022)` You have to use this option.

Answer (score 3):

You can preload the image into a javascript Image object, then check the width and height properties on that object.

Comment: Of course - I don't have to put it into the document. Will do it that way, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
/* Function to return the DOM object's in crossbrowser style */
function widthCrossBrowser(element) {
    /* element - DOM element */

    /* For FireFox & IE */
    if(     element.width != undefined && element.width != '' && element.width != 0){
        this.width  =   element.width;
    }
    /* For FireFox & IE */
    else if(element.clientWidth != undefined && element.clientWidth != '' && element.clientWidth != 0){
        this.width  =   element.clientWidth;
    }
    /* For Chrome * FireFox */
    else if(element.naturalWidth != undefined && element.naturalWidth != '' && element.naturalWidth != 0){
        this.width  =   element.naturalWidth;
    }
    /* For FireFox & IE */
    else if(element.offsetWidth != undefined && element.offsetWidth != '' && element.offsetWidth != 0){
        this.width  =   element.offsetWidth;
    }       
        /*
            console.info(' widthWidth width:',      element.width);
            console.info(' clntWidth clientWidth:', element.clientWidth);
            console.info(' natWidth naturalWidth:', element.naturalWidth);
            console.info(' offstWidth offsetWidth:',element.offsetWidth);       
            console.info(' parseInt(this.width):',parseInt(this.width));
        */
    return parseInt(this.width);

}   

var elementWidth    = widthCrossBrowser(element);
```

Comment: is `element` a jQuery selection? What is about height ?

Answer (score 2):

Just changing a little bit Gabriel's second option, to be more easy to use:

```
function getImgSize(imgSrc, callback) {
    var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function () {
        if (callback != undefined)
            callback({width: newImg.width, height: newImg.height})
    }

    newImg.src = imgSrc;
}
```

Html:

```
<img id="_temp_circlePic" src="http://localhost/myimage.png" 
style="width: 100%; height:100%">
```

Sample call:

```
getImgSize($("#_temp_circlePic").attr("src"), function (imgSize) {
    // do what you want with the image's size.
    var ratio = imgSize.height / $("#_temp_circlePic").height();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding adjustments to Gabriel's second option to help people working with react-grid-gallery.

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([])

const getImgSize = function (imgSrc, index) {
    var newImg = new Image()

    newImg.onload = function () {
        setImages((images) => [
            ...images,
            {
                id: index,
                src: imgSrc,
                thumbnail: imgSrc,
                width: newImg.width,
                height: newImg.height,
            },
        ])
    }

    newImg.src = imgSrc
}
```

In useEffect you can call this method

```
gallery_urls?.map((url, index) => {
            getImgSize(url, index)
        })
```