# get image real size JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine original size of image cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)
>   [jquery get image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038075/jquery-get-image-size)

could someone tell me how do i get the real size of an image using JS / JQ  ?
THX !
tried a lot of solutions from this site but no success...

```
var selector = $(".album_pics > img[id="+img_id+"]") ;
var old_width = selector.width() ;
```

Doesnt work..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `naturalWidth` property:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageToTest'), // or whatever...
    width = img.naturalWidth;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xh8MD/).

This does, of course, require that the image has time to load before the JavaScript is executed (so, in jQuery, using the `$(window).load()` method). It is, also, HTML5-only (which I hadn't realised until I checked, just now).

Incidentally, as perhaps the name implies, there's also the `naturalHeight` property (if that would be of use).

Updated to add a slightly more functional approach:

```
function showNaturalInfo(el) {
    if (!el || el.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'img') {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var w = el.naturalWidth,
            h = el.naturalHeight,
            D = document,
            details = D.createElement('span'),
            detailsText = D.createTextNode('Natural width: ' + w + 'px; natural height: ' + h + 'px.');
        details.appendChild(detailsText);
        el.title = 'Natural width: ' + w + 'px; natural height: ' + h + 'px.';
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(details, el.nextSibling);
    }
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; i++) {
    showNaturalInfo(imgs[i]);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xh8MD/1/).

References:

- [`naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement).

Comment: I am slightly curious as to the down-vote. I know they're occasionally somewhat random, but it'd be *nice* to know if I'd suggested something wrong, or spectacularly useless for someone. Sigh... =/