# Getting image dimensions after browser resize

Tags: javascript, image, events, resize, onload

I have a div with a image I want to center inside. The image will be different everytime and has a max-width and max-height css property. Problem is, the image.onload function I use to do the math with the image.width and image.height, gives me the images dimensions before its scaled down by the browser. :( how can I pull this off?

Comment: can you not use the css `background-position: center;` rule?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine original size of image cross browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Comment: both comments helped :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you have an image that is, say, 200x200 pixels, and has been resized to (say) 150x150 pixels because of the CSS properties, then image.width and image.height should work fine. That is, they should give you 150x150, and not 200x200. (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement) for the mozilla reference.)

Alternately, you could try element.clientWidth and element.clientHeight (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight), which give the rendered sizes of any DOM element.

I haven't tested this in IE, but it should work fine there as well. (The MSDN reference page for width is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535145%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You can also find clientWidth there.)

What browser are you testing on?