# Getting size, height and width of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I get the size, height and width of an image in when upload it with **jQuery**?

Comment: This question is not very clear.  Include a small code example and/or clarify the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are implying by "..uploade it with jQuery", but my guess is that you will find your answer here http://goo.gl/m1J8V

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine original size of image cross browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use jquery uploadify plugin then you can find the file size by any one of these following method

```
'onSelect': function(event, ID, fileObj) {
    console.log(fileObj.size);
}
```

OR,

```
'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
    console.log(fileObj.size);
}
```

and use

```
$('img').css('width');
$('img').css('height');
```

Comment: no, i not use. How can I get size?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#imgId").css('width')
$("#imgId").css('height')
```