# How to get the Image Width and Height?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

i have one image url(Online url), now i want this image height and width, how can i get this, it's greatly appreciate if anyone answer this

1. i want to preview the image with 150px height and 150px width, so i set it up in aspx page height-150 and width-150 for img tag
2. if i assign the above url to img src, it will throw the 150px width and 150px height, but i need the original height and width of the above url image
3. if i didn't set it up anything for the img tag i will get 0px of height and 0px of width

Can anyone suggest this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine original size of image cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0):

if you have the url,you can set up the url as a DIV element's background-image.

and you can display the background whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties of the img object.
See here: [Determine original size of image cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)