# Javascript: get image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I cant get correct size for image

Here is the HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/ca_serenity/misc/logo.gif"
    height="20">


<div id="result"></div>
correct result: 76
```

And the javascript:

```
var v1 = $('#image').height();
var v2 = $('#image').removeAttr('height').height();
var i =  $('<img>').attr('src',  $('#image').attr('src'));
var v3 = i.height()

i.one('load', function() {
    var v4 = $(this).height();
    $('#result').text(v1 + " " + v2 + " " + v3 + " " + v4);
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) {
        $(this).load();
    }
});
```

I used 4 methods, and all of them failed.
**Updated:** method 2 works, but I want to use method 4 because image may be not loaded at the moment of script execution.

Testing link: http://jsfiddle.net/cMZK7/7/

Comment: The correct answer is **not** 80. The `<div>` surrounding the image - which is what you're examining with `$('#image')` - is 24 pixels high because of the padding around the 20 pixel high image.

Comment: Your test code is different from the code in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1944298/1515540

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine original size of image cross browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944298/966972

(it was in comments for this question, but not in answers)

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing the DIV which the image is on, not the image itself.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code. But methods 3 and 4 still don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you're setting the `src` attribute before the `load` event.  On many browsers, this will prevent the event handler from firing.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your grabbing the height for the div with the id of image versus grabbing the height of the image inside that div. Try this:

```
var v1 = $('#image img').height();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `height` attribute, and wait until the image has been loaded (using the `load` event).

Alternatively, create a new image object, load the same image into it, and wait until the image has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are getting the height of the surrounding `div`, rather than the `img`.

`console.log($('img').height(), $('img').width())` gives me 20px and 88px, which are the correct dimensions of the image

Comment: That's the size of resized image. I want to get original image dimensions.

Comment: Ah, that was unclear from the question. Your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get it, but if the point is to find the value in the height attribute, this will work:

```
var height = $("#image img").prop('height');
```

To get the actual height of the image, and by actual height, I mean the height the image actually is, not the height you set in CSS etc., something like this should work:

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src = ​$('img', '#image')[0]​.src;
    img.onload = function() {
        $("#result").html(img.height);
    }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cMZK7/8/)

Older versions of IE will have issue with the onload event when the image is cached.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<img id="image" src="http://javascript.ru/forum/images/ca_serenity/misc/logo.gif" />

<script>
$("#image").load(function() {

    alert($("#image").height()); // Alerts 76
    });  

</script>    
​
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/FgrQW/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('<img>').get()[0].height;
```

Comment: That will create a new image element without a height attribute, so the result will be empty. Even if you get the actual height of the element, it will still not be the height of the image, as the element has no source attribute.