# jQuery calculate image height w/o css or height attrib set?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive layout with some images. The images have `max-width:100%` set. And the height cannot be preset in the CSS or the HTML `height` attribute, or else the image distorts as the responsive layout gets smaller. It has to be `height: auto;` in order to scale properly.

Is it possible to calculate the height of the image in jQuery? `.height()` and `.css('height')` relies on the css or height attrib to be set, and like I said, I cannot set those without distorting the image when the responsive design changes size.

Comment: duplicate - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem ended up being that `.height()` and `.css('height')` were returning 0 because the image(s) had not loaded yet when that code was called.

In order to get the height, I ran the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img.whatever').load(function(){
    console.log($(this).height()); // calculates height correctly after image is loaded.
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a great, common sense solution. Worked great for me, as I was having the same issue (but for some reason mine was only in Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

You can use outerHeight()

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Determine original size of image cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser) :

You have 2 options:

Option 1:

Remove the width and height attributes and read offsetWidth and offsetHeight

Option 2:

Create a JavaScript image object, set the src, and read the width and height (you don't even have to add it to the page to do this).

```
function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
    var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function() {
    var height = newImg.height;
    var width = newImg.width;
    alert ('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
    }

    newImg.src = imgSrc; // this must be done AFTER setting onload

}
```

I am sure that solution will work for you.

If you just change the height, or width of the image, it should not distort the aspect ratio.