# Get size of Image when jQuery accordion applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-ui

It seems like in jQuery when an element is not visible `width()` returns 0. 
when I remove the accordion the height is reported correctly. I tried wrapping the images in a div and setting the div's display to block , but this didn't work either.
is there any alternative to find image original size when accordion applied?

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Click me</h3>
    <div>
         <div class="bg">
               <img src="your_img_url">
         </div>
    </div>      
    <h3>Click me</h3>
    <div>
         <div class="bg">
               <img src="your_img_url"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#accordion').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
    });
    $("img").load(function() {
        alert($(this).height());
        alert($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a specific width and height on the images will return that width and height. This can be done in CSS or using the `width` and `height` attributes on the `<img>` element.

Changing your images to `<img src="your_img_url" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">` should work.

If you need original width, you could do something like this:

```
var img = $('img').clone().appendTo('body').hide();
img.load(function () {
    alert($(this).width());
    alert($(this).height());
});
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944298/401060) has more detailed information on how to get the original size.

Comment: i want image original height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me!

Do you have accordion plugin?

if not: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-accordion/

is it added to script?

- yo should remove last `,` to `collapsible: true,`

it sould look like this:

`$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#accordion').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
    $("img").load(function() {
        alert($(this).height());
        alert($(this).width());
    });
});`

But it works anyways!

Comment: accordion plugin works properly but width() and height() returns 0 for inactive content.