# jQuery - Filter Images based on actual size

Tags: jquery, image, filter, dimensions, image-size

Image sources hold true image dimensions (width/height). In a `div#pics` with 5 images, 3 images are 16X16, and 2 images are 2x2. Both the 2x2 images have a class applied to them that makes them 16x16, the other 3 images are 16x16. The problem is that, when I filter this way:

```
var Images = $('#pics img');
var FilteredImages = Images.filter(function(){
    return ($(this).width() == 16) || ($(this).height() == 16)
});
```

`FilteredImages` holds all 5 images, because it takes into consideration the class that makes the 2 2x2 images 16x16. How can `FilteredImages` hold only the 3 images that their source image size (not css), is 16x16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var Images = $('#pics img'),
    FilteredImages = Images.filter(function(){
        var that = this;
        return (that.naturalWidth == '16px') || (that.naturalHeight == '16px')
    });
```

References:

- [HTMLImageElement (`naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` are in the table)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement).

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you do var that = this in your example?

Comment: Because I like to cache variables that I use more than once; `this` (I think) doesn't involve navigating the DOM, but it's a habit I got into when accessing other nodes relative to the current `this` node/object.

Comment: David, thanks for the quick response. Just wondering, is this solution cross browser?

Comment: I totally agree with caching variables which I mostly do too, but I never cached "this" as I thought it's already cached. I'll look some more into this so I can properly get the right idea in my head. Thanks

Comment: @Wonka, to be honest, I sort of doubt it; but I don't have IE handy to test with, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pics img[width=16][height=16]').css({border:'1px solid red'});
```

Comment: This relies entirely upon the `height`/`width` attribute being set. Which isn't always the case.

Comment: That's true but the question is not specific enough so I assumed they are, for SEO and rendering purposes I always set those attributes for images.

Comment: That's fair enough, my comment wasn't intended as criticism, just a caution. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the images to a temporary object to get their original sizes:

```
function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
  var newImg = new Image();

  newImg.onload = function() {
    var height = newImg.height;
    var width = newImg.width;
    alert ('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
  }

  newImg.src = imgSrc; // this must be done AFTER setting onload

}
```

See the answer here:
[Determine original size of image cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Comment: How can `FilteredImages` hold only the 3 images that their source image size (not css), is 16x16?