# How to get the file dimensions of a selected file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is this code :-

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
  alert(this.files[0].type);
});
```

to get the file type. This code :-

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {
  alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```

to get the file size. But I could not find any jQuery API to get the file dimensions. Please tell me about any. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by file dimensions? Like image sizes?

Comment: @Waldheinz, yeah the width and the height

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine original size of image cross browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Preview Image, get file size, image height and width before upload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check image width and height on upload with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-on-upload-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904008/1230248)**

This answer already posted on stackoverflow please see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904008/1230248)**

Try this

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#myFile").change(function (e) {
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with all type of files ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll might want to let the browser decode the image to get the sizes:

1. Create an [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) for the file.
2. create an `<image>` DOM object,
3. register an `onload` event handler there
4. assign the object URL to the image