# Check image width and height from URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I check an image width and height if I only have the URL of the image, and not the image itself?

i.e. Url might be something like

http://www.myadvertiserprovider.com/images/myuserid/ad_image.png

What I am trying to do is to skip inserting an ad into my page if the image dimensions are not exactly what I am expecting.  I don't want to resize the image, I require the image to be the exact dimensions that I am expecting.

Comment: The URL contains no information about the image, just its URI; you'd have to load the image, and insert it into the document, in order for JavaScript to do anything with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine original size of image cross browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Comment: A quick google search "get height and width of image without rendering" turned up this: [Function to get image properties](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?251096-Get-image-width-without-rendering-it-to-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will  have to load the image. You can try something like

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () { 
    alert("height: " + img.height + " width:" + img.width); 
};
img.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d17c95dfa5820a212d979da58bc3435c?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8CYs2/)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done client-side without loading the image, unless the you request that the size of the image is written in the URI, something like image200x350.jpg.

If you want to load the image and check the image before placing it into your document:

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    console.log("Height: " + image.height + ", Width: " + image.width);

}

image.src = "http://tes.jpl.nasa.gov/css/homeWelcome.png";
```