# loading image using img src results in different size in Mozilla/Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser, mozilla

I am not an UI expert.
For one of the requirement to show the reload icon, I downloaded the 128x128 pixel reload icon from the link - https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/28464/recycle_refresh_reload_sync_icon

and used in my html page. Actually this was designed for a catcha page.

```
<body>
<img src="reload.ico" />
</body>
```

When opened in Firefox, this was shown as a small image, but when opened in Chrome, it is relatively large. What is the reason behind this?

I agree that after changing the code to ,

```
<body>
<img src="reload.ico" width="24px" height="24px" />
</body>
```

both the browsers are showing the same size. But i am interested to know why it was not in the first case.

**edit:** Actually I accidentally downloaded the 128x128. But then i am surprised to see this difference.

Comment: just do not use the ***.ico*** format.. Prefer the ***.png***

Comment: cool.. Searched more on .ico , and came across the point that "ico is not a standard browser image format". So excpet for favourite icon purpose, on all other places other image formats such as png, jpg are recommended.

Comment: exactly.. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support for supported formats

Comment: thank you. One more question. W.r.to this SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser it seems , even if we put as jpg/jpeg the browser sometimes resize the actual size [from the chart, Mozilla and Chrome is supported]

Comment: Also, can you post your suggestion as answer so that i can mark it as answer.

Comment: in regard to jpg files they are supported everywhere. But they do not have transparency so if you need that stick to ***.png***. As far as resizing the browser will never resize an image on its own. But it can be affected by css rules or by applying width/height attributes on the `img` tag. (*but even then only the rendering is affected, not the actual size of the image*)

Comment: Worth mentioning that .ico files can contain multiple sizes of the same image. The file in question in fact contains three images: 256x256, 16x16 and 128x128 (according to the mediainfo utility). How browsers decide which version to use to display an `<img>` element, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***.ico*** files are only supported for the favicon.

Prefer the ***.png*** files for transparent images/icons.

You can see a list of supported formats per browser at [Comparison of web browsers on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)