# How to get height of CSS manipulated image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm having some div boxes where there is an image inside. What I want it to do, is to add a class to the image if the image height is smaller than the div box its inside.

But I have set the image to be a 100% width of the div box, so when I use jquery's .Height() on the image, it gives me the original size. Any suggestions?

```
    <div class="boxe">
        <asp:Literal ID="imgProjekt1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Literal ID="litProjekt1" runat="server"/>
    </div>

    <div class="boxe forsideboxMiddle">
        <asp:Literal ID="imgProjekt2" runat="server" />
        <asp:Literal ID="litProjekt2" runat="server"/>
    </div>
```

The literal with the ID imgProjekt1 and ImgProjekt2 makes a normal img tag from codebehind.

Comment: Could you post example code? This sounds like it's something very specific to how your page is laid out.

Comment: Yes of course, it should be in the question now

Comment: OK thanks! I suspect this has to do with when you're calling `.height()`. Are you calling it in your `onReady` or somewhere else?

Comment: What happens when you call it after your image's `onload` event?

Comment: i dont get what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var myImage = $('img'),
        originalHeight = myImage.height();

    getImgSize(myImage, originalHeight, myImage[0].src);
});

/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser */
function getImgSize(myImage, currentHeight, imgSrc) {
    var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function() {
        if(newImg.height > currentHeight) {
           myImage.addClass('smaller');
            alert(newImg.height + ' > ' + currentHeight);
        }
    }

    newImg.src = imgSrc;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/43Fud/)</kbd>

## EDIT:

The class should only be added to the image when it's smaller than it's parent `div` in height. Bigger images shouldn't get the class, even if they are smaller than the source image.

Time for the code:

```
$(function() {
    var myImage = $('img');

    getImgSize(myImage);
});

/* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser */
function getImgSize(myImage) {
    myImage.each(function() {
        var that = $(this),
            parent = that.parent(),
            originalHeight = that.height(),
            parentHeight = parent.height(),
            newImg = new Image();

        newImg.onload = function() {
            if(
                newImg.height > originalHeight &&
                parentHeight > originalHeight
            ) {
               that.addClass('smaller');
            }
        }

        newImg.src = that[0].src;
    });        
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/43Fud/1/)</kbd>

Comment: it doesnt....It also takes images that are bigger than the box and makes them have the class to?

Comment: The class should only be added to the image that is smaller than the dic box they are in side, the ones that are bigger than the bow in height shouldtn get the class

Comment: I guess [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/43Fud/1/) is what you want, check it please :)

Comment: I've added the css to the class in the fiddle. Can you please check it out? Its works om my website, but when i refresh the page it sometimes add's the class to all images

Comment: About the "add's the class to all images" you've got to give me an example to test it out. Don't forget that if you put `position: absolute` to the image, the parent (div) has got to be `position: relative` so that the image stays inside the div box.

Comment: I know, but i gave up on the javascript and made it in the codebhind in .NET :) But thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: Anyway, if my answer was helpfull to your problem even though you ended up doing it another way, please accept it. Thanks!