# Javascript resize background color proportionally to its own size

Tags: javascript

I want to resize a background image 30% to its original size then use it as background to an element. I am sure my mistake is somewhere in the last line.
Here is my code :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "wallpaper.jpg";
var a = img.height;
var newWidth = (img.width*0.3));
var newHeight = (img.height*0.3));

t.getBody().style.backgroundImage = "url("+img.src+")"; 
t.getBody().style.backgroundSize = "(newWidth)px  (newHeight)px";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of `background-size` property should be like `Xpx Ypx`. Try change Your last line to this:

```
t.getBody().style.backgroundSize = newWidth+"px "+newHeight+"px";
```

Comment: @bourax I'm glad to help, but this is very dissapointing that You have accepted answer of a man, which copied mine answer ;).

Comment: @Krzysztof Trzos, Not to take in wrong way. I was actually trying this in my IDE and in addition to your reply it requires parseInt() for better handling the numbers. I am voting for your reply :-)

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see you was the first :) anyway, he upvoted you ;) Thanks both

Answer (score 1):

substitute the newWidth and newHeight values with a space in between.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "wallpaper.jpg";
var a = img.height;
var newWidth = (parseInt(img.width)*0.3);
var newHeight = (parseInt(img.height)*0.3);

t.getBody().style.backgroundImage = "url("+img.src+")"; 
t.getBody().style.backgroundSize = newWidth+"px "+newHeight+"px";
```

Comment: Note that you will want to wait for the onload event before checking the width and height http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser