# How to get dimension of uploaded image in jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am uploading image and validating that if uploaded image is greater than 500x500 then generate an error.
I am using following code to know the dimension.

```
rules: {
            profile_pic:{accept: "png|jpe?g",imagedim:true}
}

$.validator.addMethod('imagedim', function(value, element, param) { 
  var _URL = window.URL;
        var  img;
        if ((element = this.files[0])) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                console.log("Width:" + this.width + "   Height: " + this.height);//this will give you image width and height and you can easily validate here....

                return this.width >= param
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(element);
        }
});
```

But this its not returning me uploaded image height width.Every time its submitting form event if I added `return false;`
Please help

Comment: For one thing, you're incorrectly using the `accept` method in place of [the `extension` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/).  The former is for MIME type and the latter is for file extension.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a possible duplicate of this:

[Determine original size of image cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Please check it.