# How to set image width to 100% based on certain size constraints of container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The images can be wider than the width of their container or smaller than it. To control the width of larger images, I can use `max-width: 100%`. Similarly, I can also set `width:100%` for smaller images.

Is there any way to set image width to 100% only if the original image is at least 50% of its container width? I will prefer a CSS based solution if it exists because the images will load dynamically.

Comment: Please add a HTML example to your question

Comment: The **only if** part of your question is called a conditional.. those don't exist in CSS..

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: contain` or `background-size: cover`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the images will load dynamically, I think your best shot is with javascript.  You'll need to get the width of the image ([Determine original size of image cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)), and then you can compare that to the parent of the image, and determine if it's above or below 50%.

UPDATE:

Considering the question didn't provide any sample code, I didn't want to just guess. But, the pseudo code would look something like this:

```
// after ajax completes
var image = jQuery('.image'),
parent = image.parent();
if (image.width() * 2 >= parent.width()) {
   image.css('width','100%');
}
```

Comment: Linking another SO answer, does not make this an answer. Update with code examples.

Comment: How will it work if images are loaded using AJAX?

CSS will actually resize all images though. Sorry, if I am missing something. :)

Comment: you are missing something... you can't load images via ajax, it doesnt work like that.. why dont you post some code so we can see what youre really doing

Comment: @PootieTang Why can't the OP load images using AJAX?? ... I've done that many times

Comment: please post a code example so i can see what you are referring to as ajax

Comment: @PootieTang If you refer loading images as in "binary" then I am not, I mean of course an image resource ... but one actually can load it using base64, very rare though

Comment: right, you could, but that would be asinine. i was confident that wasn't what op meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
var containerDiv = $(".container");
var image = $(".img");
image.width(image.width()>containerDiv.width()?containerDiv.width():image.width());
```

Comment: Will it still work if image are loaded using AJAX. Because as far as I know the JavaScript will only run once. :)

Comment: Fire it from the AJAX response.

Comment: what on earth do you mean youre loading images via ajax??? that doesnt make any sense

Comment: @PootieTang LOL

I meant loading some HTML via ajax which contains some images.

Comment: yeah, if you put this in the ajax response function it will work

Comment: but really, it's just markup that you're loading from ajax, not images.

Comment: make sure you run that code after you add the markup to th edom though

Comment: So, this code is supposed to go after the HTML i load via AJAX inside a `script` tag?

Comment: don't put this code in the markup that you are getting from ajax, put it in the function that is actually making the ajax request.