# How to get image original width

Tags: jquery

I need to get image original width for which I'm going to change `src` attribute, this way:

```
<input hidden type="file" id="loader" accept="image/*">

$('#m1new').click(function(){
    $('#loader').click();
});

$('#loader').change(function(){
var a = this.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var src = e.target.result;
    $('#imgt').attr("src", src);
    }
reader.readAsDataURL(a);
var a = $('#imgt').width();
console.log(a);
});
```

Console says - `undefined`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-the-real-width-and-height-of-an-image-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Comment: *"Console says - undefined."* That `console.log` should be *inside* the `onload`, after setting `src`.

Comment: Look this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1944298/5596671)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#loader').change(function(){
    var a = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {

     var img = new Image();        
     img.onload = function() {
        console.log('width is: '+ img.width);             
     }; 
     img.src = reader.result; 
     }
   reader.readAsDataURL(a);       
});
```

Comment: @bonaca happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

> Console says - undefined.

That `console.log` should be *inside* the `onload`, after setting `src`, and after a `load` event on the image:

```
$('#loader').change(function() {
    var a = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var src = e.target.result;
        $('#imgt').on("load", function() { // Hook `load` first
            var a = $(this).width();       // Get the width once loaded
            console.log(a);
        }).attr("src", src);               // Set src AFTER hooking `load`
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(a);
});
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> this gives me computed width - 960px - instead of original width - 540px - in this case.

The only reason it would do that is if you have CSS applied to the element. If you do, you didn't mention it in your question. (That was *kind of important information*. )

You can get the original width from an `img` element not in the DOM (and thus not subject to CSS):

```
$('#loader').change(function() {
    var a = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var src = e.target.result;
        var img = $("<img>");
        img.on("load", function() {     // Hook `load` first
            var a = $(this).width();    // Get the width once loaded
            console.log(a);
            $("#imgt")[0].src = src;    // Now set it on the image in the DOM
        }).attr("src", src);            // Set src AFTER hooking `load`
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(a);
});
```

Comment: this gives me computed width - `960px` - instead of original width - `540px` - in this case.

Comment: @bonaca: The only reason it would do that is if you have CSS applied to the element. If you do, you didn't mention it in your question. That was **kind of important information**.

Comment: yes, css is there, but I said - `original width`. Never mind, you helped me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @bonaca: I've added to the answer.