# Get real width and height of website images

Tags: html, css, image

On every website there are plenty of oversized images. With `oversized` i mean that the real image's width and height are higher then the place, which is available for image by HTML and/or CSS rules. The cause is - images are downscaled by browser.

How is it possible to get the images from a webiste with their real and available sizes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944298/4341456

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine original size of image cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser)

Comment: where do you see possible duplicate? just compare an accepted answer, and answers in other threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your post correctly, you can use [`naturalWidth`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=img-naturalwidth-naturalheight) and `naturalHeight` to determine an image's original dimensions.

```js
img = document.getElementById('image');

img.addEventListener('load', function() { 
  console.log('width', img.naturalWidth);
  console.log('height', img.naturalHeight);
});
```

```css
#image {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/PDE3MLe.jpg" />
```