# Hide overflow behind stacked div with transparent background on top of body with SVG background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a layout that contains a `fixed` div (`#navigation`) that has buttons. The layout also includes scrollable content (`.card`).

`#navigation` currently has a green background for demo purposes. Like so:

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  background: green;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation"><button id="btn1">Button</button>
  <button id="btn2">Button</button>
  <button id="btn3">Button</button>
  <button id="btn4">Button</button>
</div>
```

I would like to hide the any part of any `.card` element as soon as it goes behind the green background. So, I use z-index stacking order and it works well. Like so:

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 1;
  background: green;
  padding: 25px;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation"><button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

However, I would also like not to use the green background in production. This means that `#navigation` should not have a background and only the buttons inside should be visible.

So my question is how do I hide the top-side overflow from `#card-wrapper` as soon as it reaches the hypothetical green background?

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: transparent
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation"><button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note, the `body` element has an SVG background, I cannot add any background to #navigation as it would look bad.

I am open to all solutions CSS/JS/jQuery as long as they do not involve hard-coded values

Comment: 1. Is it real background that should be used? 2. Is it necessary to use `background-size: cover`?

Comment: @Flying 1. Yes, the background in the last snippet is the one I intended to use, so you can base the solution on that. 2. Yes, the background fills up the entire viewport.

Comment: Your background is semi-transparent, so even if backgrounds will be synced - you will not get "invisible" block, but rather [this](http://clip2net.com/clip/m27129/f24cc-clip-4kb.png?nocache=1) appearance. Is it really what you want to get?

Comment: @Flying if you can sync the background well across devices and viewport resize then don't worry about the transparency, that's another issue I will take care of later.

Comment: In addition to browsers, you can test it on the snippet too

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to set same background for #navigation also, with same background-position (see example below)

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 40px 25px 25px 25px;
  background: #ffffff url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffffff url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation">
    <button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: nice and elegant solution. this is the way to go.

Comment: In the question the `#navigation` has a `top: 20px;`.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez you can still add that space from top with `padding-top: 20px;`

Comment: @kastriotcunaku It would be nice to add that detail in your answer.

Comment: @kastriotcunaku means is just use `top: 0;` and `padding-top: 20px;` to replace `top:20px`

Answer (score 3):

### A JavaScript Solution

**The spirit of the solution:**

`Tested on CH62, FF57 and IE11`

While kastriotcunaku's answer is good if you don't mind the formatting,
This solution maintain same parameters as those given, 
here I'll attempt to give the `#navigation` a background that looks and is positioned as the body's to give the illusion of transparency using JavaScript to make it responsive.

`Background-size:cover` on the `#navigation` div will make it looks denser. So I'll try to emulate `cover` by stretching the background to cover the whole body and still appearing only on the navigation element by :

```
navigationElement.style.backgroundSize=(document.body.clientHeight/imgH)*imgW+"px";
```

`/* imgW image width, imgH original image height. A trick to maintain the width/height ratio of the SVG. You can programmatically`[`get size of the image`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944280/determine-original-size-of-image-cross-browser#answer-1944298)
    `For some reason I've needed that even on the body for IE11 who doesn't seem to handle "cover" properly */`

For the background positioning however, there are browser differences. Surprisingly enough IE11 is the most straightforward

```js
    n=document.getElementById('navigation');    
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    var imgH=647.7;
    var imgW= 2351.2;

       function resizeHandler(){ 
            r=n.getBoundingClientRect();
            n.style.backgroundSize=(innerHeight/imgH)*imgW+"px";
            if (isChrome){
                n.style.backgroundPosition=r.width/2+"px 0px"
            } else if (isIE){
                n.style.backgroundPosition=0
        document.body.style.backgroundSize=(innerHeight/imgH)*imgW+"px";
            } else{
                n.style.backgroundPosition=-r.x+"px -20px"
            }
       }    
       addEventListener("resize",resizeHandler);
       document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded",resizeHandler);
```

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 0.1px dotted;     
  background: #ffffff url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:#ffffff  url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation">
    <button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I really, really, really, really wanted to find a solution using some new CSS features like `clip` or `backdrop-filter`. In the end, I found a solution but it definitely comes up short, and isn't as elegant as kastriotcunaku's solution.

The solution below uses the experimental [`backdrop-filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) to make the content behind a `#screen` element have `opacity(0)`. Unfortunately, there are downsides to this:

- Requires a few lines of JavaScript to set the dimensions of the `#screen` element to match the `#navigation` element - this could be avoided if the width/height/position of the `#screen` element was known in advance
- Will only work in browsers supporting the `backdrop-filter` property - mainly Safari, or in Chrome with the Experimental Web Platform features flag enabled (which you can set by going to chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features in Chrome)

The end result is:

[image]

If you're using a browser with support for `backdrop-filter` you can view it in action below:

```js
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var navigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
var navigationStyle = window.getComputedStyle(navigation, null);

screen.style.height = navigationStyle.getPropertyValue('height');
screen.style.width = navigationStyle.getPropertyValue('width');
screen.style.border = navigationStyle.getPropertyValue('border');
screen.style.borderColor = "transparent";
```

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#screen,
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  padding: 25px;
}

#screen {
  backdrop-filter: opacity(0%);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: opacity(0%);
}

#navigation {
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bkg {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="screen"></div>
  
  <div class="bkg"></div>
  
  <div id="navigation">
    <button id="btn1" onclick="alert()">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  

</div>
```

If the width/height of the `#screen` and `#navigation` are fixed we do away with the JavaScript.

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#screen,
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  padding: 25px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 71px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#screen {
  backdrop-filter: opacity(0%);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: opacity(0%);
}

#navigation {
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bkg {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="screen"></div>
  
  <div class="bkg"></div>
  
  <div id="navigation">
    <button id="btn1" onclick="alert()">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your navigation as fixed navigation and only allow scroll to your content area. For that you have to add `position: absolute;` to `#card-wrapper` and remove `display:inline-block` from `.card` .

```css
#card-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  clear:both;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: transparent
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation"><button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

After a nice bit of trial and errors, I've got this solution that I think it's the best so far

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25%;
  right:25%;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  border-top: 0.1px dotted;    
  border-bottom: 0.1px dotted;
  background: white url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg) top left/cover no-repeat fixed;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg) top left/cover no-repeat fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation">
    <button id="btn1">Button</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button</button>
    <button id="btn3">Button</button>
    <button id="btn4">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to have fixed value for the `height` of the buttons - then your task can be solved through `background-clip` style. In example below I've also added click handlers for cards and buttons to demonstrate that cards are still clickable.

```js
$('.card').on('click',function(){
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
})
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.card').removeClass('clicked');
})
```

```css
#card-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #131418;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: inline-block
}

#navigation {
  background-image: url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/**
calc() calculation values:
 25px - .buttons-list padding  
 20px - top offset of #navigation (it is also padding-top value)
 30px - button height;
*/
  padding: 20px 0 calc(100vh - 25px * 2 - 20px - 30px);
  pointer-events: none;
}

button {
  height: 30px
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(http://svgur.com/i/42T.svg);
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
}

.buttons-list {
  padding: 25px;
  pointer-events: initial;
}

/* Just for click events demonstration */
.card.clicked{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

  <div id="navigation">
    <div class="buttons-list">
      <button id="btn1">Button</button>
      <button id="btn2">Button</button>
      <button id="btn3">Button</button>
      <button id="btn4">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```